# Is $5 = -5$ according to this formula?

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

Today in maths class something occurred to me. How can this be:

> $\sqrt{(-5)^2} = ((-5)^2)^{1/2} = (-5)^{2(1/2)} = (-5)^1 = -5$
>   $\sqrt{(-5)^2} = ((-5)^2)^{1/2} = 25^{1/2} = 5$

This could theoretically prove that $5$ equals $-5$.

Is there any logical reason to explain this?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $((-5)^2)^{1/2}$ doesn't actually equal $(-5)^{2(1/2)}$.

Comment: This kind of exponentiation only works for real numbers greater than or equal to zero. There is some funny business when you try to exponentiate negative numbers.

Comment: $25^{1/2} =  5$ or $-5$

Comment: Related: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10488/student-converted-sqrtx2-and-ended-up-with-just-x-instead-of-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Technically,* the $\sqrt{x^2}$ could be $±x$ because $x^2 = (-x)^2,$ but the convention is to only use the positive root for reasons elaborated in the links Jack's wasted life and mweiss provided.